# How to find x2 and y2

Tags: php, math, geometry

I have the following for a rectangle.. **x1,y1,width and height**

How can I find **x2 and y2** having the values of above?

Comment: Given these four random numbers, produce two other random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw `(x1, y1)` on a piece of paper with a coordinate system and then draw a rectangle of dimensions `width x height` on the same paper.

If you make `width = 0`, you can say that `x1 = x2`. If the widths gets any larger, then `x2 > x1`. You can say that `x2 = x1 + width`.

The height works the same way, so `y2 = y1 + height`.

I assumed that `(x1, y1)` is the bottom-left corner's coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the point which is represented by x1,y1 and the point you refer to when you say x2,y2 we have the following outputs:-

If x1,y1 is the **leftmost-bottom point** of the rectangle

then the other 3 points are `x1+width,y1`,`x1,y1+height`,`x1+width,y1+height`

If x1,y1 is the **rightmost-bottom point** of the rectangle

then the other 3 points are `x1-width,y1`,`x1,y1+height`,`x1-width,y1+height`

If x1,y1 is the **leftmost-top point** of the rectangle

then the other 3 points are `x1+width,y1`,`x1,y1-height`,`x1+width,y1-height`

If x1,y1 is the **rightmost-top point** of the rectangle

then the other 3 points are `x1-width,y1`,`x1,y1-height`,`x1-width,y1-height`